# Are CLLocationCoordinates lat/lon values Locale Dependent?

Tags: ios, locale, cllocation, nslocale, cllocationcoordinate2d

I turn CLLocations into comma-separated strings such as "75.45874, -45.17292" simply by using an [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f, %.5f"]; and send them to my server application, which expects the string as two numbers with decimal points as the decimal separator.

After reading through all the docs, I can't for the life of me figure out if those coordinates are locale dependent or not, i.e. if a user was overseas (I'm in the US) would their location have a comma as the decimal separator: "75,45874, -45,17292"?

I know a few different ways that I could translate the comma to a decimal if needed, like using an NSNumberFormatter, I'm just trying to figure out if I'd actually need to or not? I've tried simulating locations with the simulator, but I don't know if the locale settings would trickle down to a CLLocation's latitude/longitude properties and would properly emulate such a situation. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates in a `CLLocation` are represented as `CLLocationDegrees` which is defined as `double`. This are floating point numbers and not locale dependent.

Creating a string with

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f, %.5f", lat, lon]
```

is also not locale dependent. `stringWithFormat` (almost) conforms to the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)
which defines the `%f` conversion as

> The double argument shall be converted to decimal notation in the
>   style "[-]ddd.ddd", ...

So your code will always produce a *point* as decimal separator.

On the other hand, `NSNumberFormatter` uses the user's locale preferences for the conversion
unless specified otherwise. You *can* use it in your case if you set the locale to the standard
"POSIX locale":

```
NSNumberFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```